# how to get the negative response code in java

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I am using the code as follows in java.

```
 URL url = new URL("any url");

  HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

  InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();

  int responseCode= conn.getResponseCode();
```

Here I am getting the issue:-
   for some url,I am getting the negative reponseCode,that is `'-1'`.and it is getting terminated,it is not going further,so please help me,how to solve or how to handle such errors.

Comment: Are the affected URLs valid and create a response? The documentation states that -1 is returned if the response code can't be determined.

Answer (score 3):

From the JavaDoc of getResponseCode:

It will return 200 and 401 respectively. Returns -1 if no code can be discerned from the response (i.e., the response is not valid HTTP).

Answer (score 1):

`-1` is not a error it returns if no code can be discerned from the response, see [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode%28%29)

```
URL url = new URL("any url");
HttpURLConnection conn=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

if(responseCode == -1) {
    // no code can be discerned
}
```

Comment: Returns -1 if no code can be discerned from the response (i.e., the response is not valid HTTP). What`s mean:the response is not valid HTTP?